# Matlab: ode45 output incorrect for forced spring mass damper

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

Here is my Matlab code to solve the second order ODE for a mass-spring-dashpot system:

```
function Spring

clear all;
close all;
options=odeset('RelTol',1e-6); 
p0 = [1 0]; %initial position and velocity
[t,p] = ode45(@SpringFunction, [0 20], p0, options);

plot(t,p(:,1)) %plot the first column (x) vs. time

return

function pdot = SpringFunction(t,p)

c = 5; w = 2;
g = sin(t); % forcing function
pdot = zeros(size(p));
pdot(1) = p(2);
pdot(2) = g-c*p(2)-(w^2)*p(1);

return
```

I believe the output I am getting is wrong because for this case I think a plot of displacement vs. time should look like a sinusoid with decreasing amplitude. Instead, it looks like this:
[image: decreasing function which relaxes to a sinusoid whose amplitude is constant]

This seems incorrect to me, but please correct me if I'm wrong. I cannot see what is incorrect in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sinusoidally forcing a damped system so you should expect the steady state to be a sinusoid. Here's [a nice vibrations tutorial](http://www.math.uah.edu/howell/DEtext/Part3/Springs2.pdf) (PDF) – see pp. 448–450 on damped sinusoidal forcing. Try removing the forcing or greatly reducing its amplitude. Also, it looks like you have a lot of damping. Your [damping ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio), ζ (zeta), appears to be `c/(2*w) = 5/4`. This implies that the unforced form of your system is over-damped – with no forcing you won't see oscillation.

Also, be careful using `ode45` with oscillatory systems. If your system happens to be too stiff, you may either need to adjust the tolerances or use a stiff solver such as [`ode15s`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15s.html) to get accurate results. You can always try using tighter tolerances to check that they yield qualitatively similar results (same period, amplitude, rate of growth/decay, etc.).